Managing Tomcat urls with apache
I would like to access the tomcat urls via Apache such that i can forward requests from tomcat to apache as below
Unfortunately I cannot access https://host.com as I am getting Forbidden ( no permissions to app1). Any suggestions would be appreciated.
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName host.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/server.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine on

    # Proxy requests to the backend server (Tomcat)
    ProxyPass /app1 https://server.com/app1
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 https://server.com/app1

    <Location />
        Require all granted
        Header edit Location ^https://server.com/app1(.*) https://host.com/$1
        Header edit Set-Cookie "(.*)" "$1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None"
    </Location>

    ErrorLog logs/server_error_log
    CustomLog logs/server_access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

client denied by server configuration: /etc/httpd/htdocs -> from error.logs
